# Как вызвать событие родительского компонента из child компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь вызвать событие родительского элемента из child. 
Вот родительский:

```
<template>
    <header>
        <div v-if="this.userInformation === undefined" @click = "startLogin = true" class="login-panel">
            <img :src="image_src">
            <label>Sign in</label>
        </div>
        <login-component v-on:close-modal="closeLoginPage" v-if="startLogin === true">

        </login-component>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </header>

</template>

<script>
    import LoginComponent from "./LoginComponent";
    export default {
        components: {LoginComponent},

        name: "HeaderComponent",
        data: function () {
            return {

                image_src: '/img/icon-user.svg',
                startLogin: false
            }
        },
        methods: {

            closeLoginPage: function () {
                this.startLogin = false;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Вот child:

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-login">
            <button class="class-button" v-on:click="this.$emit('close-modal')">Close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-overlay" id="modal-overlay"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "LoginComponent",
        data: function () {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Но событие не вызывается и пишет this.$emit is not a function. 
Что я делаю не так и как это лучше реализовать, заранее спасибо.

Comment: а если убрать `this.`?

Comment: еще тут уберите `this.userInformation === undefined`. Вы пишите и `v-on:event="..."` и `@event="..."`, лучше использовать второй вариант и использовать только один стиль во всем проекте.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько а чем this.userInformation === undefined плохо?
Спасибо за замечание про event

Comment: @Grundy ексепшен ушёл, но метод не выполняется

Comment: `this.userInformation === undefined` содержит this, с ним по идее не должно работать. Попробуйте `@closeModal`, по моему в атрибутном html стиле не работает запись событий.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, забыл вписать. userInformation это пропс)

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько решение было убрать this перед emit + ответ снизу)

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sidebar-sponsors-special

> ```
> this.$emit('myEvent')
>
> <my-component v-on:my-event="doSomething"></my-component>
> ```

в вашем случае:

```
<button class="class-button" v-on:click="$emit('closeModal')">Close</button>
```

1. имя - `closeModal`
2. `$emit` - т.к. объявление в `html` разметке - `this` не нужен

! в js всё же будет необходимо писать так: `this.$emit`

---

если мой ответ вам не помог - рекомендую:

1. в вопросе указать версию VueJS
2. задать вопрос в чате - https://chat.vuejs.org/

Comment: Можете добавить, подалуйста, что this не надо и я приму ответ)

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич, отредактировал. похоже на правду?

Comment: да, спасибо большое)